# How to use d3-shape curve factories on geojson (D3 v4)

Tags: javascript, geojson, d3.js

How might I use the curve factories in d3-shape to smooth / interpolate geojson lines and polygons? As far as I understand the API, I can pass a list of coordinates, get an SVG line string back from:

```js
var line = d3.line(coords).curve(d3.curveCatmullRom.alpha(0.5));
```

What I want is an array of coordinates that I can construct a LineString from.

I *think* I need to define a context that returns coordinates. There is plenty on rendering *from* geojson to svg linestrings but I can't find any information on rendering *to* geojson coordinates.

Comment: You want to pass in a list of coordinates and return a list of smoothed coordinates?  `d3.line` renders a path to a canvas context or returns an svg `path`'s `d` (data) attribute.  It just doesn't do what you are asking.

Comment: Yes that is what I want. After reading more through the d3 v4 source code, I think what I would need would be a custom context that rendered to coordinates, which would need to implement the [CanvasPathMethods](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#canvaspathmethods) similar to [d3-path](https://github.com/d3/d3-path/blob/master/README.md#path) - not as easy as I thought it would be.

Comment: Yes, interesting idea.  The problem will be the curves: `quadraticCurveTo`, `bezierCurveTo`, etc..  These aren't just coordinates but rather drawing instructions.